# Brew Install is same of yum?

Tags: linux, yum, brew

I have a question about package management on OS. Brew is a package-management utility like Yum?

Someone have any idea about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and `yum` are package managers: they allow you to install, upgrade, and remove packaged pieces of software along with their dependencies.

There is a significant difference between the two in practice: on systems using `yum`, `yum` manages all the system’s software, whereas Homebrew is an “add-on” package manager. Homebrew installs packages alongside whatever system it runs on. For example, on macOS, if you install `coreutils` with Homebrew you’ll have both `coreutils`’ `ls` (accessible through `/usr/local`) and the original macOS `ls`. On `yum`-based systems, you can use Homebrew to install packages alongside the `yum`-managed packages.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen Kitt for the information, very clear, About the " Add-on" Do you know some other manager, that I could use in the same of Yum in Mac, for that have managed the system software?

Comment: macOS manages the system software itself, you shouldn’t try to replace that (and I don’t think there is a third-party package manager which will do this anyway).